# Saving a command prompt input to a text file

Tags: logging, command-prompt

I'm using the git command prompt and want to save series of commands and its output to a file so it will make it easier to post on forums etc.  How do I do this and how to I specify where the file is saved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cut & paste should work...

Comment: seems a little obvious but I didn't know I had an option to cut and paste.  Works fine though, thanks